# Historical daily data for VIX futures using IB API

Tags: c#, interactive-brokers

I am able to get historical data for just about any symbol, but for some reason, getting historical data for VIX futures doesn't work for me.

This is the way I call the IB API. The symbol I use is `VXU9`:

```cs
System.DateTime today = System.DateTime.Now;
Contract c = new Contract();
c.Currency = currency;// "USD";
c.SecType = secType;// "FUT";
c.LocalSymbol = symbol;//VXU9
c.Exchange = "CFE";
barsKindStr = "1 day";
string_timeframe = "2 D";

ReqHistoricalData(id, c, today.ToString("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss"), 
                  string_timeframe, barsKindStr, "TRADES", useRTH, 1, keepUTD);
```

Comment: What doesn't work?  What is the error and check your logs.  CFE isn't in the US futures $10 data package.  Historical data requires a subscription.

Comment: I get the  realtime data as I can see it in TWS.

Comment: Are you sure the TWS data isn't delayed?  Hover over it.

Comment: Bizarre. I was told by IB API support that I had subscribed to it, but when I hovered over it, it clearly showed delayed data and gave me a link to subscribe to the CFE. Once I did that, it works. Thanks.